# How to initialize a tuple class in implementation in java

Tags: java, initialization, tuples, implementation

```
class Term <Base, Power>{ //declaration of new class Term
    Base a;
    Power b;
    public Term(Base a, Power b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}


public static void in(){ //trying to use this class in another class's method
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");
    Term<Integer, Integer> t;
    t.a = input.nextInt();
    t.b = input.nextInt();


}
```

I get an error that "t might not be initialized."  I don't understand how to go from making generics like Base and Power and using them as integers, and everything I try seems to be wrong.  I could really use some help but I don't think I am understanding the terminology enough to do a search for it.

Thanks for any help.

edit: Thank you very much!

Comment: `Term<Integer, Integer> t;` is not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t` is not initialized because you never assign anything to it. Here is one way you can fix this:

```
int a = input.nextInt();
int b = input.nextInt();
Term<Integer, Integer> t = new Term<Integer, Integer>(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `t` variable has no value.

You need to put a `new` instance of your class into it, just like any other class.